# How do I avoid overwriting member variables initialized in a superclass in Scala with an underscore?

Tags: scala, inheritance, reflection

My superclass initializes member variables through reflection via annotation-based injection.  How do I prevent a subclass from overriding the value of a member variable set by the superclass?  The problem is that the primary constructor of the superclass initializes the subclass's member variable and then the subclass's primary constructor (which is called subsequently) writes over that value when the member variable's declaration is executed.

Comment: FYI, This came up in the context of playing around with args4j in Scala.  I was creating my own Options class whose member variables were annotated with the `@Option`.  I then had the class's primary constructor take a string array of args and initialize the member variables with args4j CmdLineParser.  I then tried to subclass my Options class but the member variables annotated with `@Option` in my subclass were not getting initialize correctly until I initialized them with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I discovered is to initialize the subclass's member variable with an underscore.  This is actually explained quite nicely in the language specification in section 4.2 which talks about giving variable's initialized with an underscore a getter function that returns its current value.